# Error al ingresar ionic cordova build android

Tags: android, ionic, cordova

[image: Error al generar el siguiente comando ionic cordova build android necesito ayuda para este problema]

Error al generar el siguiente comando ionic cordova build android necesito ayuda para este problema

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Por favor pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score -1):

¿tienes instalado e android estudio?, parece un problema con las variables de entorno.

si tienes instalado el android estudio deberías de configurar la variable ANDORID_SDK_ROOT

para comprobar que las variables estan bien ejecuta en el terminal:

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

en mi caso la salida es:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools\n
```

Para poner las variables de entorno en mi mac uso:

```
export PATH="/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/santiago/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0 ":$PATH 

ANDROID_HOME= /Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tool
```

luego ejecuta:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```